# How to add rewrite in bitnami site

Tags: php, wordpress, bitnami

I have created new bitnami site and added some rewrite rules for some pages. All pages work fine except one link which is camera details link.

Cameras list page link work fine as I expected

```
http://{site-domain}/public/cameras
```

But detail link does not work

```
http://{site-domain}/public/cameras/ruthin-school
```

I am using following rule for detail page:

```
<rule name="Show public camera details" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^/?public/cameras/([^/]+)$" ignoreCase="true" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="/public/cameras/index.php?{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami developer here.

Maybe that's not working because Apache is the one who is making the redirection to other pages, so I highly recommend you to move that configuration to the `/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/htaccess.conf`file.

Here is the guide about writing the rules for apache, is pretty similar to the rules you are using now:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html